# How to trigger form submission with button outside the form with form being created dynamicaly based on selection from a dropdown menu?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, sql

So I have a basic form with three input fields and a drop down menu that dynamically creates three diff forms. A button in the navbar "Add Product" Without the drop down menu the data is captured and stored into database. With the drop down menu it doesn't seem to work. Yes I am a newbie and I am appreciate your help.

PHP Code

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['add_product']))
{
include('./database.php');
echo "<script>console.log('add button clicked');</script>";

echo "add button clicked";
    $Sku = isset($_POST['product_sku']) ? $_POST['product_sku'] : "";
    $Name = isset($_POST['product_name']) ? $_POST['product_name'] : "";
    $Price = isset($_POST['product_price']) ? $_POST['product_price'] : "";

    $Size = isset($_POST['p_size']) ? $_POST['p_size'] : "";

Create and execute the INSERT query
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `pdvd`(`product_sku`, `product_name`, `product_price`,`p_size`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param('ssss', $Sku, $Name, $Price, $Size);
    $stmt->execute();



Check if the query was successful
if ($stmt->affected_rows === 1)
{
echo 'Data was successfully inserted into the database.';
        //The follwoing echo's was just for my testing purposes
echo "$Sku";
echo "$Name";
echo "$Price";
echo "$Size";
else {
echo 'Failed to insert data into the database.';
    }
}

?>
```

HTML PAGE CODE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- The following code assumes that the dropwdown menu items are static items.
    If a user would wish to add more "dataTypes" the code would have to be re-adjusted so that users can create "dataTypes" and then
    poplate this list with these "dataTypes" from the database. -->
    <script>
        function showForm(formId)
        {
            document.getElementById(formId).style.display = "block";
        }

        function hideForm(formId)
        {
            document.getElementById(formId).style.display = "none";
        }

        function handleDropdownChange(event)
        {
            let formId = event.target.value;

            let formElements = document.querySelectorAll(".form");
            formElements.forEach(element => {
                hideForm(element.id);
            });

            showForm(formId);
        }
    </script>

    <title>Adding Products</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg m-3" style="background-color:azure">
        <h1 class="navbar-expand-lg">Product Add</h1>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">

                    <button class="btn btn-primary m-1" type="submit" name="add_product" href="./ProductAdd.php" form="form">Add Product</button>

                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary m-1" href="index.php">Cancel</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>




    <hr class="my-5" />

    <!-- Form -->
    <form id="form" class="form-col" id="product_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>">


        <!-- SKU -->
        <div class="form-group row m-5">
            <label for="product_sku" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">SKU</label>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="product_sku" name="product_sku" method="post">
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Name -->
        <div class="form-group row m-5">
            <label for="product_name" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="product_name" name="product_name" method="post">
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Price -->
        <div class="form-group row m-5">
            <label for="product_price" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">Price ($)</label>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="product_price" name="product_price" method="post">
            </div>
        </div>



        <!-- Type Swithcer -->
        <div class="form-group row m-5">
            <label for="productType" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">Type Switcher</label>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <select class="custom-select" id="productType" name="productType" onchange="handleDropdownChange(event)">
                    <option value="form0">Typeswitcher</option>
                    <option value="dvd">Dvd-Disc</option>
                    <option value="furniture">Furniture</option>
                    <option value="book">Book</option>
                </select>


                <div id="form0" class="form" style="display: none;">
                    <!-- Form 0 elements here -->
                </div>
                <div id="dvd" class="form" style="display: none;">
                    <!-- Form 1 elements here -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="p_size">Size (MB) :</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="p_size" name="p_size" method="post" placeholder="Size in (MB)" required title="Please enter the Size (MB) of your product.">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="furniture" class="form" style="display: none;" method="post">
                    <!-- Form 2 elements here -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="p_length">Length (CM) :</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control w-200" id="p_length" name="p_length" method="post" placeholder="Length in (CM)" required title="Please enter the length of product.">
                        <label for="p_width">Width (CM) :</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control w-200" id="p_width" name="p_width" method="post" placeholder="Width in  (CM)" required title="Please enter the width of your product.">
                        <label for="p_height">Height (CM) :</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control w-200" id="p_height" name="p_height" method="post" placeholder="Height in (CM)" required title="Please enter the height of your product.">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="book" class="form" style="display: none;" method="post">
                    <!-- Form 2 elements here -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="p_weight">Weight (KG) :</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="p_weight" name="p_weight" method="post" placeholder="Weight in (KG)" required title="Please enter the weight of your product.">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <!-- <input type="submit" name="add_product" value="Add Product"> -->


        </form>



    </body>

    </html>
```

When I use the input type submit button inside the form (currently commented out) without the drop down menu and the javascript code to handle the selection from the drop down menu. The data is being captured and stored to DB.
When I include the drop down menu nothing happens when the button is clicked.
To top it off the button to submit the form data needs to be in the navbar.

Comment: Have you checked the browser console(f12)? Network tab to see if anything is being sent? The web server error log?

Comment: hi, this link is an example for button outside form :: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_button_form

Answer (score 0):

The problem, or one of them perhaps, is that the `form` contains **all** the elements regardless of whether or not they are displayed and they have the `required` attribute set. The fact that only a single section is displayed at a time does nothing to affect the other, non-visible elements which are unable to gain `focus` and thus can never be completed by the user. The following is an alternative approach which puts the form section content outside the form within `Template` elements which can be loaded as necessary when the user makes a selection from the dropdown menu.

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
        exit(sprintf('<pre>%s</pre>',print_r($_POST,true)));
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
    
    
    
        <!-- Navbar -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg m-3" style="background-color:azure">
          <h1 class="navbar-expand-lg">Product Add</h1>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <button class="btn btn-primary m-1" type="submit" name="add_product" href="./ProductAdd.php" form="form">Add Product</button>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="btn btn-primary m-1" href="index.php">Cancel</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
        
        
        <hr class="my-5" />
        <!-- Form -->
        <form name='products' id="form" class="form-col" id="product_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        
          <!-- SKU -->
          <div class="form-group row m-5">
            <label for="product_sku" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">SKU</label>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="product_sku" name="product_sku" method="post">
            </div>
          </div>
          
          <!-- Name -->
          <div class="form-group row m-5">
            <label for="product_name" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="product_name" name="product_name" method="post">
            </div>
          </div>
          
          <!-- Price -->
          <div class="form-group row m-5">
            <label for="product_price" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">Price ($)</label>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="product_price" name="product_price" method="post">
            </div>
          </div>
          
          <!-- Type Switcher -->
          <div class="form-group row m-5">
            <label for="productType" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">Type Switcher</label>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
              <select class="custom-select" id="productType" name="productType">
                <option selected hidden disabled>Typeswitcher
                <option data-form=1 value="dvd">Dvd-Disc
                <option data-form=2 value="furniture">Furniture
                <option data-form=3 value="book">Book
              </select>
              
              <!-- dynamically added content will be added here -->
              
            </div>
        </form>
        
        
        
        <!-- 
            Form content will not be visible until added to the form dynamically.
        -->
        <template data-form='1'>
          <div id="dvd" class="form">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="p_size">Size (MB) :</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="p_size" name="p_size" method="post" placeholder="Size in (MB)" required title="Please enter the Size (MB) of your product.">
            </div>
          </div>
        </template>
        
        <template data-form='2'>
          <div id="furniture" class="form">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="p_length">Length (CM) :</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control w-200" id="p_length" name="p_length" method="post" placeholder="Length in (CM)" required title="Please enter the length of product.">
              <label for="p_width">Width (CM) :</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control w-200" id="p_width" name="p_width" method="post" placeholder="Width in  (CM)" required title="Please enter the width of your product.">
              <label for="p_height">Height (CM) :</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control w-200" id="p_height" name="p_height" method="post" placeholder="Height in (CM)" required title="Please enter the height of your product.">
            </div>
          </div>
        </template>
        
        <template data-form='3'>
          <div id="book" class="form">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="p_weight">Weight (KG) :</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="p_weight" name="p_weight" method="post" placeholder="Weight in (KG)" required title="Please enter the weight of your product.">
            </div>
          </div>
        </template>
        
        
        
        <script>
            /*
                The select menu options each have a dataset attribute that refers 
                to the particular content that is to be added dynamically.
                
                Via the change event  we can identify the selected option and from
                that deduce the dataset value.
                
                Any previously added form content is cleared before new content
                is added to the form.
                
                With that selected value we then find the relevant Template and clone 
                the contents so that we can add it to the DOM.
            */
            const changehandler=(e)=>{
                let oSelect=e.target;
                
                let i=oSelect.options[ oSelect.options.selectedIndex ].dataset.form;
                
                let oTmpl=document.querySelector(`template[ data-form="${i}" ]`).content.cloneNode( true );
                
                oSelect.parentNode.querySelectorAll('div.form').forEach( div => {
                    div.parentNode.removeChild( div );
                });
                
                oSelect.parentNode.appendChild( oTmpl );
            };
            
            document.forms.products.productType.addEventListener('change',changehandler)
            
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```